# rpi 3 kernel headers

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ubuntu-16.04, raspberry-pi3

I'm using a RPi 3 Model B with [Ubuntu Mate 16.04](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/).

I wanted to install a library, but it required kernel headers to be installed.

The output of `uname -r` is `4.9.66-v7+`.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, but apt-get couldn't find it.

(I also tried using [these](https://www.niksula.hut.fi/~mhiienka/Rpi/linux-headers-rpi/), but this error was returned: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`.)

Where can I get header files?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache search linux-headers-4`?

Comment: @GAD3R only headers for 4.4.0, 4.8.0, 4.10.0, 4.11.0, and 4.13.0.

Comment: Run `apt dist-upgrade` then reboot or install a new linux-image (4.10.0 ; 4.11.0 ot the 4.13.0) then reboot to install the appropriate linux-headers.

Comment: `apt dist-upgrade` returns with "nothing to upgrade". For the rpi3, I can only update the kernel with `sudo rpi-update`, and the latest raspberry pi firmware is version 4.9.67. So there's no way I can update to any of the newer kernel versions.